# Using IEditableObject In Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a object that implements the IEditableObject interface exposed on a viewmodel bound to a Silverlight page.

How/Where do I call the BeginEdit, CancelEdit and EndEdit methods? How can I constrain only objects implementing this interface to my page?

I am NOT using DataGrid or DataForm controls. I am using Label, TextBox and DescriptionViewer controls to display the data for editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old thread (but for the sake of future use...)

I do it this way:

whenever the current item (for instance of a CollectionViewSource) changes this is done:

```
void View_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (culturesView.Source != null)
            {
                ((IEditableObject)SelectedRecord).BeginEdit();
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedRecord");

            }
        }
```

Whenever i want to save (the current item) i do this:

```
 private void Save()
{
 ((IEditableObject)SelectedRecord).EndEdit();
//do the actual saving to the dbms here ....

}
```

Whenever i want to cancel (current changes) i do this:

```
private void Cancel()
{            
((IEditableObject)SelectedRecord).CancelEdit();
            //allthough we have canceled the editing we have to re-enable the edit mode (because
            //the user may want to edit the selected record again)
            ((IEditableObject)SelectedRecord).BeginEdit();

}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future!

Comment: Although this isn't an exact answer to some of my questions, the sample code gave(and the time that has passed since I posted this question) have given me some ideas. Thanks!