# How to implement IEditableObject for View Model?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, mvvm

Suppose I have VM with some entities as property. Say People, Addres, Phone, ....
Then I want to implelemt IEditableObject  on VM so that user have undo functionnality.

What's the best way to implement request?

Demo code please.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at following two links which have good examples

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=135

[Using IEditableObject In Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278942/using-ieditableobject-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

`IEditableObject` doesn't make sense on a view model since all commands from the view such as Edit, Cancel, etc. are implemented in the view model itself. At best you can use `IEditableObject` internally in your view model on the data classes to make them easier to manage.

Comment: I'd say that IEditableObject doesn't make sense on a view model, in the case that you control your model classes.  Currently I'm working on an app with engineering data that I have to wrap in view models for unit conversion etc, I implement IEditableObject on those view models, as I can't implement it on the models coming in.

Comment: Ultimately, it could make sense to implement `IEditableObject` either on Model or on View-Model, depending on a lot of conditions specific to each application. Remember that this interface is not MVVM specific, so the edition itself might be an intrinsic characteristic of an entity, or otherwise might sometimes be only a desire for a specific View.